# Guzzle with Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm working on Lavravel 9 with guzzle to send some data in

the below code need to get some data from the database how can get data from the database?.

```
$response = Http::post('APIurl', [
        "headers" => [
            //header information
        ],
        "body" => [
            'title' => "**Get data from database**",
            'body' => "**Get data from database**,
            'userId' => 22
        ],
    ]);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API returns a json result, simply call the `json()` method on the `Response` object. If you want the raw response body, use `body()` instead.

For example, take github's api:

```php
$response = Http::get('api.github.com'); // replace with your call
$body = $response->body();               // returns string
$json = $response->json();               // tries to return a json array.
```

---

To add data to your request, try passing a json string in the body.

```
$data = json_encode([
    'title' => ...,
    'body' => ...,
    'user_id' => ...,
]);

$response = Http::post('your-api-here', [
    'headers' => [
        ...
    ],
    'body' => $data,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need to fill body data from data inserted in database. How can get it, that's what I mean

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try passing in a json string instead of an array to the body of your request. You might also need to specify the Content-Type header as application/json